# Error compiling Grails 2.4.2 application when adding Spring Security Rest plugin to BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.4, spring-security-rest

I have a **Grails 2.4.2** application working with Spring Security Core and I'm trying to implement a Restful API with authentication. For this, just added **Spring Security Rest v1.5.4** as a plugin in my BuildConfig.groovy file, as follows:

```
    grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
    grails.tomcat.nio=false
    grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
    grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
    grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
    grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
    grails.project.target.level = 1.6
    grails.project.source.level = 1.6
    grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"
    grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
    grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
        inherits("global") {
        }
        log "info" 
        checksums true
        legacyResolve false
        repositories {
            inherits true

            mavenCentral()
            grailsPlugins()
            grailsHome()
            mavenLocal()
            grailsCentral()
            mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
            mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
            mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases-local"
            mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
            mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot"

        }

        dependencies {
            compile('com.lowagie:itext-rtf:2.1.7')
            compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7') {
                excludes "commons-logging", "xml-apis", "groovy", "xercesImpl"
            }
            compile 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8'

            test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.41.0")
            test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.2"

            compile 'org.grails.plugins:events:1.0.0.M1'
            compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE'
            compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.5.RELEASE'
            compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE'
            compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
            compile ('eu.medsea.mimeutil:mime-util:2.1.3'){
                excludes([group:'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.5.6'])
            }
            compile ('org.apache.poi:poi:3.10.1'){
                 excludes "xml-apis", "xercesImpl", "stax-api"
            }
            compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.10.1'){
                 excludes "xml-apis", "xercesImpl", "stax-api"
            }
            compile ( group:'org.springframework.cloud', name:'spring-cloud-starter-eureka', version:'1.0.0.M2', changing: true){
                excludes "logback-classic", "xercesImpl", "tomcat-embed-core", "tomcat-embed-el", "stax-api", "hibernate-validator", "log4j-over-slf4j"
            }
            compile ('com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:2.0-RC9'){
                excludes "xercesImpl",  "stax-api"
            }
            compile ('com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:2.0-RC9'){
                excludes "xercesImpl",  "stax-api"
            }
            provided ('xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1'){
                excludes "xml-apis", "stax-api"
            }
            compile 'br.com.caelum.stella:caelum-stella-core:2.1.2'
            compile ('br.com.caelum.stella:caelum-stella-boleto:2.1.2'){
                excludes('itext')
            }
        }

        environments {
            test {
                dependencies {
                    runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.9.RELEASE'
                    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
                }
            }
            production{
                dependencies {
                    runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.9.RELEASE'
                    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
                }
            }
            development {
                dependencies {
                    runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.9.RELEASE'
                    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
                }
            }
        }

        plugins {
            test ":geb:0.9.2"
            build ":tomcat:7.0.54"
            compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
            compile ':cache:1.1.7'
            compile ":rest:0.8"
            compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
            compile ":spring-security-rest:1.5.4"
            compile ":mail:1.0.6"
            compile ':mongodb:3.0.3'
            compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"

            runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"

            compile ':console:1.4.2'
            compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
            compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.1"
            compile ":mongodb-create-drop:1.0"
            compile (":export:1.6"){
                excludes "xml-apis", 'itext', 'itext-rtf', "xercesImpl", "stax-api"
            }
            compile (":rendering:1.0.0")
            compile ":br-validation:0.3"
            compile ":google-analytics:2.3.3"
            compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
            compile ":jslint:0.6"
        }
    }
```

When I execute the run-app command, the following errors are shown:

    `Compiling 279 source files
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: /tmp/groovy-generated-68181663753307402-java-source/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/AccessToken.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
      [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
      [groovyc] /home/aescobar/IdeaProjects/lasa-portal-fornecedores/portal-web/target/work/plugins/spring-security-rest-1.5.4/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/storage/TokenStorageService.groovy: -1: The field 'instanceEventsApi' is not 'public static final' but is defined in interface 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.TokenStorageService'.
      [groovyc]  @ line -1, column -1.
      [groovyc] /home/aescobar/IdeaProjects/lasa-portal-fornecedores/portal-web/target/work/plugins/spring-security-rest-1.5.4/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/oauth/OauthUserDetailsService.groovy: -1: The field 'instanceEventsApi' is not 'public static final' but is defined in interface 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.oauth.OauthUserDetailsService'.
      [groovyc]  @ line -1, column -1.
      [groovyc] 2 errors
    | Compiling 279 source files.
    | Error Compilation error: startup failed:
    /home/aescobar/IdeaProjects/lasa-portal-fornecedores/portal-web/target/work/plugins/spring-security-rest-1.5.4/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/storage/TokenStorageService.groovy: -1: The field 'instanceEventsApi' is not 'public static final' but is defined in interface 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.TokenStorageService'.
     @ line -1, column -1.
    /home/aescobar/IdeaProjects/lasa-portal-fornecedores/portal-web/target/work/plugins/spring-security-rest-1.5.4/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/oauth/OauthUserDetailsService.groovy: -1: The field 'instanceEventsApi' is not 'public static final' but is defined in interface 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.oauth.OauthUserDetailsService'.
     @ line -1, column -1.
    2 errors`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. I can see the error, but since I didn't write any code lines, I don't know what I'm possibly missing. Is this a configuration error? A dependency error? Am I forgetting to write some code?

I can't find a hint about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try excluding `spring-security-core` from `spring-security-rest` plugin? It can be done like this:

```
 compile ":spring-security-rest:1.5.4", {
     excludes: 'spring-security-core'
 }
```

Or maybe try different versions of those plugins: for me the combination of `spring-security-core:2.0-RC4` with `spring-security-rest:1.5.0.M2` (with mentioned exclusion) works well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found what was causing the conflict. It was the `org.grails.plugins:events:1.0.0.M1` library that was included.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for everyone who tried to help me.

I discovered the problem was that the dependency `spring-security-rest:1.5.4` conflicts with `org.grails.plugins:events:1.0.0.M1` library.

I don't really need to use this specific events library, so I just removed it from my project. Now, everything works just as it was supposed to.

Thank you.